# Regex expression for Apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anybody suggest what would be regexp for String, which validates following conditions:

1. Can contain characters a-z or A-Z. At least one should be there.
2. Can contain  (space), '(apostrophe), -(hyphen), .(dot)

Anything other than this set, such as special character or number or anything else, would be an invalid character.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z\s'\-\.]+` You're looking for a class with the `+` quantifier.

Comment: [read some tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), you should easily be able to work this out on your own

Comment: @BradChristie: You would probably want start and end anchors too: `^[a-zA-Z\s'\-\.]+$`

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP wants a-z to be compulsory and the rest to be optional. `[a-zA-Z\s'\-\.]+` would match `"'-."`

Comment: @Bungus: Good point, well spotted

Comment: @musefan: Not giving away the farm here, just showing an example. I still believe in helping those that help themselves. They can take it the other 10%. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
 /^[a-zA-Z' \.\-]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z' \.\-]*$/
```

Which translates to 'at least one letter surrounded by zero or more of any valid character'.

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't answer gimme codez questions but hey it's Friday!

There are perhaps thousands of questions here on SO following the same pattern:

```
Plz help me with a regular expression for a string that
- _must_ contain at least one X
- _can_ contain Y
```

and the answer is usually something like

```
/^ Y* X [XY]* $/
```

or if you're fancy

```
/^ (?=.*X) [XY]+ $
```

Unfortunately, all these answers (or, rather, these questions) are wrong. The problem, as usual, is that the specs are incorrect - the asker takes some "good" examples and describes them in the question, but doesn't realize that this description also matches many "bad" cases. When taken literally, this question will be answered with an expression that only does a half of its work - yes, it does validate good cases, but it does not reject bad ones. A good expression must do both!

Example: I want to validate a telefone number, which is something like `123` or `123-456-789`. So I post a question on SO:

```
Plz help me with a regular expression:
- must contain at least one digit
- can contain a dash
```

and in a few seconds I get

```
/^-*\d[\d-]*$/
```

which I test with my examples (works!) and insert in my code. On the next morning, to my deepest embarassment, someone registers on my site providing this "telefone number":

```
----------3-----------
```

The moral of the story: never validate "strings". Validate domain objects!

To answer this specific question: I can't provide you with a good regular expression until you tell me what it is for.